# Integration test HttpClient using ASP.NET Core 2.0 How to mock DateTime.Now with dependency injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, asp.net-core-2.0

Ive written a couple of unit tests while using dependency injection and the httpClient in the .net Core 2.0 framework.
Ive been testing my controllers like this:

```
var result = await  __client.PostAsync("api/production-line/validate-assignment-deadline", null);
```

But now i wanted to mock an object and after searching a bit on the internet all i could find was to do it like this:

```
var controller = new ProductionLineController(mockProductionLineProvider);
```

which is not testing the routing and on top of that i would have to create a lot of objects. so i dont want mock my object in this way.
I would like to be able to replace the service with an mock object i havent found a way to get the IServiceCollection into my unittest method.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
    var mockingDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 12, 00, 00);
    __constantsMock.Setup(x => x.GetCurrentDateTime()).Returns(mockingDate);
        services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IConstants), ConstantsMock.Object));
var result = await  __client.PostAsync("api/production-line/validate-assignment-deadline", null);
```

I hope you can help me think of ways to get to a solution that doesnt involve me having to create every object that i would inject normaly.

Thank you in advance

edit:
im indeed doing integration tests, i want to test everything but i need to be able to configure the result coming from a DateTime.Now so i made the constants class with a function to return the datetime.now and im trying to mock/stub the class/function. that way i can test multiple scenario's that could occur.

Comment: *which is not testing the routing* - You would need to setup unit tests for your routes separately. As @ChrisPratt pointed out if you test them together you have an *integration* test and that would involve more setup. You should clarify whether you intend to write unit tests or integration tests for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the standard way of mocking; you create stubs for all the dependencies (you need to be able to control all of them!) and create the controller. Being able to mock the DI framework wouldn't really buy you anything; you would still need to provide all the dependencies to the class when you constructed it.

Use mocking libraries like NSubstitute to make it easier; if you feel like you have too many dependencies then I would suspect you need to refactor your design (perhaps that controller does too much).

Note that testing with actual HTTP requests is more of an integration test; you are testing the whole app instead of just one class. In that case you can set up different environments for your program and have one that will set up the injector with whatever extra mocks/test data you need.

Comment: Ive changed the question a bit.
Im indeed doing integration tests and i need to mock a datetime.now, to make it easier to test i made an extra class called constants that has a function to return the datetime.now. i need to either mock the class or stub the function to return the value i need for my scenario's.

Answer (score 1):

Once you start doing something like issuing a request to an action, you're pretty much well outside of unit test territory. What you're doing here is integration testing.

As long as you're doing integration testing, you might as well use `TestServer`, which will actually give you a much more accurate platform for integration tests. Setting up all the dependencies manually doesn't do anything for you in ensuring that your application actually functions as it should. The full documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing), but basically, you just do:

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>());
_client = _server.CreateClient();
```

The return of `_server.CreateClient()` is actually an instance of `HttpClient`, so your actual test code doesn't really need to change. However, now you've got a full mockup of all your services and config baked in.

Comment: Thank you for your response, im indeed doing integration tests and im using the testserver. i just cant figure out how to properly mock a certain service im trying to inject. To do a proper integration test i need to be able to mock a DateTime.Now so i created the constants class with a function for getting the datetime.now and injected it thinking i would be able to mock it and replace it with a value that i need for certain tests.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was as follows:

- Make an extra starting class that inherits from your StartUp class
- Give that class the following code:

  ```
  public class UnitTestStartup : Startup
  {
      public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;
      public static IServiceCollection Services;
      public static Mock<IConstants> ConstantsMock; 

      public void ConfigureTestingServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {

              ServiceProvider = base.ConfigureServices(services);
              Services = services;
              ConstantsMock = new Mock<IConstants>();

              services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IConstants), ConstantsMock.Object));
      }
  }
  ```
- Make the ConstantsMock (the service you want to mock) available in your baseclass
  Like this:

  ```
  protected Mock<IConstants> __constantsMock;
  __constantsMock = UnitTestStartup.ConstantsMock;
  ```
- have every unit test class inherit from your baseclass
- override the `__constantsMock` with a new object and you're done